# Strange #define in Template?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, coding-style, c-preprocessor

I've got a small bit of code from a library that does this:

```
#define VMMLIB_ALIGN( var ) var

template< size_t M, typename T = float >
class vector
{

...

private:
// storage
VMMLIB_ALIGN( T array[ M ] );

};
```

And you can call it by doing

```
//(vector<float> myVector)
myVector.array;
```

No parenthesis or anything.

what?

---

After reading the answers, it appears I should've done more looking.  XCode's "Jump to Definition" gave me only one result.  Searching the library gave me another:

```
#ifndef VMMLIB_CUSTOM_CONFIG
#  ifndef NDEBUG
#    define VMMLIB_SAFE_ACCESSORS
#  endif
#  define VMMLIB_THROW_EXCEPTIONS
#  ifdef VMMLIB_DONT_FORCE_ALIGNMENT
#    define VMMLIB_ALIGN( var ) var
#  else
#    ifdef __GNUC__
#      define VMMLIB_ALIGN( var ) var __attribute__((aligned(16)))
#    elif defined WIN32
#      define VMMLIB_ALIGN( var ) __declspec (align (16)) var
#    else
#      error "Alignment macro undefined"
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

This offers different settings, depending on what system it's building for.

Regardless, thanks.  Can't believe I got confused over a member access!

Comment: How is myVecetor declared? Assuming it's an instance of your class template, the statement you have shown is legal but not especially useful, and certainly not a 'call' to anything.

Comment: wow... I guess Objective-C has really poisoned my mind.  I didn't recognize an ivar access...  Thanks guys.

Comment: I got downvoted for being stupid!?  wow... thanks.  as if `#define` s and `templates` are basics of every programming language out there.

Comment: Yeah, a few people here seem to think the purpose of downvoting is to hit people over the head. Your question seems valid enough to me, so +1 from me

Comment: tnx.  language differences get me every time, as I also work in ObjC and Java... some of the differences are really, really vast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, `myVector.array` refers to the array variable in the class, and variables don't need the function-calling notation `()`.

BTW / all-capital identifiers should only be used for preprocessor macros (as they are here).  In this case, the macro `VMMLIB_ALIGN` must be being used to make it easier to later "enchance" the code generated for and alongside the `array` variable (e.g. prefixing it with static, extern, const, volatile or something compiler-specific) and/or adding some associated functionality such as get/set/search/clear/serialise functions that work on the array.

In general - when you're not sure what the macro is doing, you can get more insight by running the compiler with a command-line switch requesting preprocessor output (in GNU g++, the switch is `-E`)... then you'll be able to see the actual source code that the C++ compiler proper deals with.

EDIT - few thoughts re your comment, but too long to include in a comment of my own...

C++ classes are private until another access specifier is provided (but in practice the public interface is *normally* put first so the programmer still must remember to explicitly use `private`).  structs are public by default.  So, data is effectively exposed by default in the most common coding style.  And, it doesn't need functional-call semantics to access it.  Objective-C may well be better at this... your comment implies you use functional call notation for data members and functions, which is hidden by default?  It's so good to have a common notation!  In C++, the difficult case is where you have something like...

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y;
};

...

// client usage:
this_point.x += 3 - that_point.y;
```

...then want to change to...

```
struct Point
{
    double angle, distance;
};
```

...you'd need some pretty fancy and verbose manually-coded and not terribly efficient proxy objects x and y to allow the old client code to keep working unmodified while calculating x and y on the fly, and updating angle and distance as necessary.  A unified notation is wonderful - allowing implementation to vary without changes to client source code (though clients would need to recompile).

Comment: ok, I just assumed that the underlying array of the vector would be hidden or something.  Buh... Objective-C is getting to me.

Comment: To answer your additional comments, in Objective-C all members are private, and use getters/setters because of the default ref-count memory management.  `[object setMember: newValue];` or for a get `int myNum = [object member];`  I was looking to see what kind of syntax in C++ didn't require the `()` because I haven't accessed a public member in forever!  Plus, templates are tricky for me to read.

Answer (score 3):

maybe I'm oversimplying, but if you look at the #define macro it just writes the variable into the class.

So you have

```
class vector
{
...
  T array[ M ];
};
```

after the expansion.  So it's just a public variable on your class.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is not a method, it's an array of type `T` of size `M`.

Answer (score 1):

First, for the record, templates have nothing to do with this. There is no special interaction between the macro and the fact that your class is a template.

Second, going by the name of the macro, I'd guess it is meant to ensure alignment of a variable.

That is, to get an aligned instance `x` of a type `X`, you'd use `VMMLIB_ALIGN(X x);`

In practice, the macro does nothing at all. It simply inserts its argument, so the above results in the code `X x;` and nothing else.

However, it may be that the macro is defined differently depending on the hardware platform (since alignment requirements may vary between platforms), or over time (use a dummy placeholder implementation like this early on, and then replace it with the "real" implementation later)

However, it does seem pointless since the compiler *already* ensures natural alignment for all variables.